Let's actually vote on our help-center sections!
Every now and then we see a clarification and minor change of the scope of Crypto.SE here on Meta, e.g. our resolution on side-channel considerations being on-topic as well as explicitly clarifying on cryptocurrencies. This has brought me the following idea:
Let's actually put the help-center into the hands of the community!
More concretely this means:

You suggest one replacement of the current content on one of the editable resources in an answer.
The answer gets voted on, depending on whether people want to see this idea (+1), don't have a strong feeling (+0) or actively dislike the idea (-1).
After one month, on the third of September, the vote results are tallied and implemented.
Updates need to reach at least +6 as a score to be even considered (to show they have community support).
Conflicts will be resolved via intelligent merging by the mods or an extra Meta Q&A.

What can be updated?

Each paragraph of the On-Topic page (separately).
New paragraphs can also be added to the On-Topic page.
The short description displayed at the top of the Tour and at the top of the page when not logged in.
The bullet points on the Tour (both are separate contents).
The introduction to the Help Center (which is empty for us, but set on e.g. Bitcoin.SE).

What do answers have to contain?

A title / TL;DR for quick identification.
A naming of the resource to be added / updated.
The new content (ideally with changes being highlighted if they are somewhat minor).
A rationale / motivation for the update.


I have put the example question out-of-scope because apparently we can only choose from 4 system-picked ones (?). // There won't be default answers because that would get way too big.

If you mean the example questions on the site tour, they have to be short (400 chars or less, I think) and have at least two short answers. And there are also limitations on what formatting the question and answers can contain. Back when I last brought it up, we only had two eligible questions, so four is an improvement.

Looks like the community either a) is fine with the help center exactly as it is, b) doesn't really care all that much and/or c) is too busy to think of any good suggestions. (For me, personally, it's pretty much a little bit of each.)
